# How to add user's first name in Order Processing Email (woocommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add user's first name to the order processing email; using this template.
[customer-processing-order.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/emails/customer-processing-order.php)

I am trying to output "Hi Users_First_Name" before "Your order has been received and is now being processed..."

I tried several ways to include order object but nothing worked.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you customize woocommerce/emails/customer-processing-order.php email template, you will get $order object by default in that file. You can get meta information from post_meta for that order id like this :

```
get_post_meta($order->ID,'_billing_first_name', true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding

```
<p><?php printf( __( "Hello %s", 'woocommerce' ), $order->billing_first_name ); ?></p>
```

before

```
<p><?php _e( "Your order has been received and is now being processed. Your order details are shown below for your reference:", 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
```

Let me know if it works.